# Dynamic filtering on relationship in ThingsBoard

Tags: thingsboard

I am building a dashboard where assets are organized into different "regions" using relationships. This is similar to the examples shown in [ThingsBoard documentation](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/entities-and-relations/#relations). In this documentation, a device belongs to a field asset which belongs to a region asset.

I want the user to be able to filter all assets/devices that belongs to a selected region. To my knowledge, this is possible using (static) alias entity filter with a "relations query". However, this doesn't seem to be possible using (dynamic) filters, which typically work on entity attributes. The final goal is to list all available "regions" on the dashboard and to filter the data source of a (e.g. map) widget so only related entities are returned.

What is the recommended approach to implement this? Should I store the region in an attribute of all related assets? Could the region attribute be injected dynamically using rule chain? Or is there a way to perform a "relations query" dynamically?